# Is a transition metal with 7 d electons ever diamagnetic?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, magnetism

A transition metal with 7 d electrons forms a complex ion with cyanide. I know that cyanide is a high field ligand, which means the electrons will pair before moving to the next energy level, but wouldn't there still be one unpaired electron? And wouldn't that make it paramagnetic? I was told that my prediction was wrong and that it was in fact diamagnetic, but I don't understand why.

Comment: With an octahedral or tetrahedral field, you cannot have a ground-state electron configuration containing 7 electrons and all of them paired; therefore, it cannot be diamagnetic.  Is it possible that the person to whom you were speaking meant your calculation of the valence electrons when s/he said your "prediction was wrong"?  Is there a specific compound in question?

Comment: It's a fake transition metal with 7 d electrons that forms a 3+ charge. The comment my evaluator left just said that my prediction was paramagnetic and that a correct prediction is not present. Was I incorrect in saying that there would be one unpaired electron? I'm not really sure what i did wrong

Comment: I think the question is whether there are 7d electrons in the ***atom*** or in the ***ion***. For example, if you take 3 electrons from 7, you get 4d electrons in the $\ce{M^{3+}}$ ion which obviously could (and should) be diamagnetic.

Comment: It sounds like @GeoffHutchison has the right interpretation: a d7 metal, after forming a +3 charge, would have 4 electrons remaining and could be  diamagnetic.  If it is a hypothetical free ion, however, then the aufbau principle would still predict a paramagnetic species with four unpaired electrons (and one unfilled d-orbital).  Something is misleading about your evaluator's question.

Answer (score 3):

As I noted in my comment above, I think the question is whether there are 7d electrons in the ***atom*** or in the ***ion***.

For example, if you take 3 electrons from 7, you get 4d electrons in the $\ce{M^{3+}}$ ion which obviously could (and should) be diamagnetic.

This is all, of course, a guess given what little you posted.

Let's say I had a similar question in my class. Students might then assume this $\ce{M^{3+}}$ is octahedral. (Personally, I'd make it a bit more obvious in the question.)

Given that the ligand is high-field, you get an initial MO diagram like this:

[image: d4-high spin]

***But...*** we're not done. This electron configuration is subject to a weak [Jahn-Teller distortion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahn%E2%80%93Teller_effect). So you'd end up with an MO diagram like this:

[image]

That, of course, is diamagnetic.